# Postgres authentification failed with odoo.conf

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Running odoo with the -c parameter cause the authentification to postgres fail. It work perfectly without this parameter.

I already tried changing password for 'odoo' user in postgres to 'admin'.

Here is my odoo.conf :

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = admin
;addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons
```

And here is the command line that doesn't work:

```
./odoo-bin -c debian/odoo.conf
```

Why is it working without this parameter ? There are not another odoo.conf on my computer.

Comment: Without using a config file, Odoo will start with default values. For both db_user and db_password the default is `False`. Are you sure the db user odoo is existing? Do you get any logs when starting with the config file?

Comment: I don't know odoo, but `db_host = False` or `db_port = False` look wrong to me. Shouldn't they contain proper values? E.g. `localhost` or `5432`?

Comment: Thank you @CZoellner your answer helped me a lot. Putting False at db_user worked for me. 
And now I understand what are the default values :)

Answer (score 0):

you are supported to config your postgresql server in odoo.conf file:

like this:

```
db_host = 192.168.88.128
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons,/home/kevin/codes/osc_addons,/home/kevin/codes/enterprise-12.0
```

and don't forget to give your db_user(odoo) proper access rights in postgresql.

also, make sure your postgresql server is opened for your code server.